Retrieve transaction history for SPL token mint address
I would simply like to be able to retrieve the transaction history for a specific token by providing its address, regardless of which wallet bought or sold the token, and regardless of whether the wallet still holds the token or not.
I tried with getSignaturesForAddress(), however the function only works with public wallet address rather than token mint address.
Is that possible at all?
Thanks.

getSignaturesForAddress also works with token mint addresses. It might not include all transfers though, since SPL Token transfers do not always require the mint to be included.
